# Add text string to new column (A) and repeat each row until reaching certain row with pre-existing value in original column (B)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So here is essentially what I would like to do:
Say I have column B, and in a cell of column B is the name of a restaurant, after that cell in subsequent rows are a list of employees in column C. This pattern continues with each restaurant. What I would like to do is have it so that the cell value in column B (restaurant name) copies over to column A for every row with an employee name in column C, until it reaches a new restaurant name in column B, and then have the process repeat. Every restaurant name will have the word "Place" in it. I'd like to do this so I can concatenate the restaraunt with the employee name to allow for a double V lookup. Here is an illustration:

[image: Example]

I would prefer to do this in google script since I am going to be copying a sheet with this format to a spreadsheet which contains a master template with vlookups pointed at this restaurant sheet and would thus like to build it in one fell swoop. Thank you for any and all help.

Update:
Thanks Tanaike, here is what it is currently doing:
Before:
[image: Before]

After (below at the end of the sheet):
[image: After]
I'm happy with this, I was just wondering if that values in the respective cells of columns, D, E, and F can come down as well (like C), and that would do it for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to achieve the result of below "What I want" in the image of your question.

  - There are 3 columns in the active sheet.
  - 1st row is `["", "Restaraunt", "Employees"]`
  - The data starts from 2nd row.
- You want to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Sample script:

When you use this script, please open the sample sheet and run the script. By this, the result values are put to the bottom of the existing values.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); // or ss.getSheetByName(name);
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();
  var n = "";
  var res = values.map(function(row) {
    if (row[1]) {
      n = row[1];
      return row;
    }
    return [n, "", row[2]];
  });
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 3, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);

//  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

#### Note:

- This sample script is for the sheet of the image in your question. So when you want to use the script to the sheet with other format, the script might be required to be modified. Please be careful this.
- In this sample script, the result values are put to the bottom of the active sheet. When you want to put the values to other sheet, please use `ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);`. At that time, please replace the sheet name of `Sheet2` to yours.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Edit:

- In your actual situation, there are values ("female", "male") except for `The Burger Place` and `The Sushi Place` in the column "B". And you want to ignore the values.

I understood like above. If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); // or ss.getSheetByName(name);
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();
  var n = "";
  var res = values.map(function(row) {
    if (row[1].indexOf("Place") != -1) {  // Modified
      n = row[1];
      return row;
    }
    return [n, row[1], row[2]]; // Modified
  });
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 3, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);

//  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

- If you don't want to put the values of "female", "male", please modify `return [n, row[1], row[2]];` to `return [n, "", row[2]];`.

Comment: Thank you as always Tanaike. I made a slight mistake in my description, it turns out in Column B there are two other string values that show up "male" and "female". Would it be possible to have your script do the same function it did, but when it encounters these two values in B to ignore them and continue copying the Restaurant name to A?

Comment: @Warren Meroney Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thank you Tanaike, made my life alot easier! One last little question if you have time. The function does everything I want it to, and I thought I could change this myself, but I'm confused, can I get it to copy the respective values from columns d, e, and f too, like it currently does with column C?

Comment: @Warren Meroney Thank you for your response.